# Excel’s cursor/selection focus after inserting content add-ins

Tags: excel, office-js

In Excel, I’m having my cursor/selection on a specific cell. Up until a recent Office update, the behavior upon inserting an Office.js-powered “content add-in” was like this:

- The add-in is being inserted
- The container of the web control is focused (you get the resize handles and Excel reveals the Drawing Tools menu) and the focus on the sheet is lost
- `getSelectedRange()` right now would not yield any results but an error
- You need to make at least one click into the web control’s area to de-focus the container and focus both the web control and re-focus the cursor/selection on the sheet
- `getSelectedRange()` works now

After a recent update, I’m using Excel for Office 365 Version 16.0.11328.20362 now. And the behavior changed to this:

- The add-in is being inserted — *unchanged*
- The container of the web control is focused and the focus on the sheet is lost — *unchanged*
- `getSelectedRange()` right now would not yield any results but an error — *unchanged*
- Clicks on the web control don’t change the focus anymore, the container keeps being focused!

While the old behavior was already cumbersome as interaction between the add-in and the sheet was not possible directly after add-in insertion (only after at least one click), now not even the workaround of making that single click in the add-in is working anymore.

My original requirement was to read data from the sheet that has been selected just prior to inserting the add-in (just like it works with the native Excel charts). That’s why I had to come up with this one-click workaround in the first place.

What is now the best (if any) way to work with the workbook/sheet right after inserting the add-in with as few quirks as possible?

Comment: This might be a bug in the build. I recommend that you raise this issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.

Comment: Thanks, @RickKirkham – a [bug report](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/670) has been filed in the office-js repo.